# Convert hex to alphabet

Tags: string, go, formatting, hex

How do I obtain the alphabet value from the hex value in Go?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := []byte{0x61}
    c := hex.Dump(a)
    fmt.Println(c,a)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/7iAs2kKw5v

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) format ([example](http://play.golang.org/p/mZTh7oY1au)):

```
func main() {
    a := []byte{0x61}
    c := hex.Dump(a)
    fmt.Printf("'%+v' -- '%s'\n", c, a)
}
```

Output:

```
'00000000  61                                                |a|
' -- 'a'
```

The `%s` format is enough to convert the `0x61` in '`a`'.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little misleading.

Based on your question what you really want is convert a `byte` value or a `[]byte` (byte slice) to a `string` or character (which is more or less a `rune` in Go).

Henceforth I will separate the single `byte` value from the `[]byte` using these variables:

```
b := byte(0x61)
bs := []byte{b}
```

To convert it to a `string`, you can simply use a conversion which is the cleanest and most simple:

```
s := string(bs)
```

If you want it as a "character", you can convert it to a `rune`:

```
r := rune(b)
```

Another solution is using [`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) as mentioned in [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28884608/1705598) and using the `%s` verb which is:

```
%s  the uninterpreted bytes of the string or slice
```

You might want to take a look at these alternatives:

```
%c  the character represented by the corresponding Unicode code point
%q  a single-quoted character literal safely escaped with Go syntax.
```

`%q` accepts both a `byte`, `[]byte` and `rune`.

See this litte example to demonstrate these (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/GM-ILRIS1t)):

```
b := byte(0x61)
bs := []byte{b}

fmt.Printf("%s\n", bs)
fmt.Printf("%c\n", b)
fmt.Println(string(bs))

fmt.Printf("%q\n", bs)
fmt.Printf("%q\n", b)
fmt.Printf("%q\n", rune(b))
```

Output:

```
a
a
a
"a"
'a'
'a'
```

If you need the result as a `string`, you can use the [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) variant mentioned in [satran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28884608/1705598) like this:

```
s := fmt.Sprintf("%s", bs)
```

But it's easier to just use the `string` conversion (`string(bs)`).

Comment: I picked up on the "misleading" part but tried a straightforward answer first, waiting for the OP to clarify. Yours is much more complete. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the string you can you `fmt.Sprintf`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := []byte{0x61}
    c := fmt.Sprintf("%s", a)
    fmt.Println(c)
}
```